# How can I exclude pull requests from git mirror clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to mirror clone a Bitbucket Repository to another Bitbucket Repository.
I manage this with a shell script, which does the following:

```
git clone --mirror <sourceUrl>
git remote set-url --push origin <targetUrl>
git push --mirror
```

Now I'm getting the following error when pushing because Bitbucket does not allow to push pull requests (which are created on the Source Bitbucket):

```
remote: You are attempting to update refs that are reserved for Bitbucket's pull
remote: request functionality. Bitbucket manages these refs automatically, and they may
remote: not be updated by users.
remote:
remote: Rejected refs:
remote:         refs/pull-requests/21/from
remote:         refs/pull-requests/23/from
remote:         refs/pull-requests/23/merge
remote:         refs/pull-requests/24/from
remote:         refs/pull-requests/24/merge
To ...
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/21/from -> refs/pull-requests/21/from (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/23/from -> refs/pull-requests/23/from (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/23/merge -> refs/pull-requests/23/merge (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/24/from -> refs/pull-requests/24/from (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/24/merge -> refs/pull-requests/24/merge (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

I solved the Problem with a Hint from http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-mirror-a-github-repository-without-pull-refs.html by adapting the fetch refs with the following workaround.

I created a new bare Repository and adapted the config the following way:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    url = <sourceUrl>
    mirror = true
    pushurl = <targetUrl>
```

Then I perform a Git Pull and Git Push and everything is fine.

Nevertheless the Workaround is not a beautiful solution because creating an empty bare repository and then overwriting it is weird so I want an alternative.

**Questions:**

- I can add the needed fetch Configuration with "git clone --config" (before git clone performs it's initial fetch) but can I remove the original `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` Configuration also with the "git clone" Command? This would solve the problem, that the Pull Requests are pulled initially
- Is it possible to remove the pull requests from the bare repository after the pull?
- Is it possible to exclude the pull requests from the push?

Comment: is this a local bitbucket server, or bitbucket.org? I didn't know the latter could pull pull requests. I can't reproduce.

Comment: It's a local Bitbucket Server.

Comment: `git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull-request' | xargs -L1 git update-ref -d`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan.

His command solved my Problem. I only had to add the "-r" parameter to xargs to react on empty greps:

```
git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull-request' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d
```

Comment: It is worth noting that even though this command purges pull request references, the same error can occur, making you think it didn't work. It does work and it might be necessary to re-fetch Bitbucket into the mirror and try again. For me -r is unsupported and I don't include it.