# How can i create a reusable CircleCI slack ORB

Tags: wordpress, circleci, orb

As circleCI devs know, circleCi notifications are depreciated in favor of ORBs.

I require to enable Slack notification and have started to use the `circleci/slack@3.4.2` package

My circleCI config.yml file has x amount of commands which are as below:

```
commands: 
  build-mu-plugins:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Clone mu-plugins
          command: |
            git clone git@github.com:Automattic/vip-go-mu-plugins.git mu-plugins && cd mu-plugins && git submodule update --init --recursive && cd .. 
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-mu-plugins' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK 
  build-base-composer:
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            # CircleCI Fingerprint in newsuk repo
            - fxxxxxxxx99:c5:2c
      - run:
          name: Install composer inside root directory
          command: composer install -n
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-base-composer' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK  
  build-wp-simple-saml:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install composer packages for wp-simple-saml
          command: composer install --no-dev --working-dir=plugins/wp-simple-saml/ -n --prefer-dist
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-wp-simple-saml' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK
```

In principe the above works , however as each `- slack/status` is pretty much the same i am questioning if there is a more effective way of configuring the ORB in EACH command

Can

```
- slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-base-composer' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK
```

Be put into a parameter or something similar so that i could perhaps repeat simply with out having all the ORB defined in each command

Perhaps something like

```
**orb-message** <<
    - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-base-composer' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK  

commands: 
  build-mu-plugins:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Clone mu-plugins
          command: |
            git clone git@github.com:Automattic/vip-go-mu-plugins.git mu-plugins && cd mu-plugins && git submodule update --init --recursive && cd .. 
      # - ORB Message 
      - **orb-message**
```

Im quite new to circleCI but struggling to find some documentation on this

My complete circleCI file is below ::

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  slack: circleci/slack@3.4.2
  
commands: 
  build-mu-plugins:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Clone mu-plugins
          command: |
            git clone git@github.com:Automattic/vip-go-mu-plugins.git mu-plugins && cd mu-plugins && git submodule update --init --recursive && cd .. 
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-mu-plugins' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK 
  build-base-composer:
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            # CircleCI Fingerprint in newsuk repo
            - xxxxxxxxxx
      - run:
          name: Install composer inside root directory
          command: composer install -n
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-base-composer' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK  
  build-wp-simple-saml:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install composer packages for wp-simple-saml
          command: composer install --no-dev --working-dir=plugins/wp-simple-saml/ -n --prefer-dist
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-wp-simple-saml' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK
  build-academy-composer:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install composer inside academy theme
          command: |
            composer install --working-dir=themes/newsacademy/ -o -n
            composer --working-dir=themes/newsacademy/ php:lint
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle:  $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-academy-composer' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK 
  build-nuk-newsuk-okta-plugin:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install composer packages for News UK OKTA Plugin
          command: composer install --no-dev --working-dir=plugins/nuk-wp-okta-plugin/ -n --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
      - run:
          name: Lint nuk-wp-okta-plugin 
          command: composer php:lint-okta
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-nuk-newsuk-okta-plugin' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK
  build-plugin-loader:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install composer packages for News UK OKTA Plugin
          command: composer php:lint-plugin-loader 
      # - ORB Message 
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle:  $CIRCLE_USERNAME your Job $CIRCLE_JOB failed build-plugin-loader !' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK 
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.3-node-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - build-mu-plugins
      - build-base-composer
      - build-nuk-newsuk-okta-plugin
      - build-plugin-loader
      - build-academy-composer
      - build-wp-simple-saml
      #- run: npm install
      #- run: npm run build
      #- run: vendor/bin/phpunit
      # TODO: Configure build steps here ^^^^^
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ./
          paths:
            - ./

  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.3-node-browsers
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ./
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            # CircleCI Deploy Fingerprint in wpcomvip repo
            - xxxxxxxxxx
      - run:
          name: Deploy -built branch to github
          command: bash <(curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/vip-go-build/master/deploy.sh")
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: false
          #channel: 'CS70KQ92N' use this if you want to deliver to a different channel other than the hook
          only_for_branches: master
          success_message: ':ok_hand: JOB $CIRCLE_JOB has been successful deploying to production' 
          failure_message: ':red_circle: JOB $CIRCLE_JOB has failed deploying to production!'
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK 
  # Sync job runs every time to ensure we keep the News UK repository in sync with the VIP repo
  sync:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2020.01
    steps:
      # Run standard checkout to get the appropriate SSH keys installed, but then remove afterwards
      - checkout:
          path: checkout-tmp
      - run:
          name: Cleanup temporary checkout
          command: rm -rf checkout-tmp
      # Do the actual mirror & sync
      - run:
          name: Mirror clone from VIP repository
          command: git clone --mirror ${CIRCLE_REPOSITORY_URL} readonly
      - run:
          name: Remove GitHub PR references
          # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985275/how-can-i-exclude-pull-requests-from-git-mirror-clone/39764408#39764408
          command: cd readonly && git show-ref | cut -d ' ' -f2 | (grep 'pull' || true) | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            # CircleCI Sync Fingerprint in newsuk repo
            - xxxxxxxxxxx
      - run:
          name: Add the News UK repository as the readonly remote
          command: cd readonly && git remote add readonly git@github.com:newsuk/nuk-newsuk-wp.git
      - run:
          name: Push mirror to News UK (readonly) repository
          command: cd readonly && git push --mirror readonly

workflows:
  version: 2
  sync:
    jobs:
      - sync
  build_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - staging
                - develop
                - master
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
                - staging
                - develop
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured this

i can run a command in a command and so
define like

```
commands: 
  orb-message:
    steps:
      - slack/status:
          fail_only: true
          only_for_branches: develop,staging,master
          failure_message: ':red_circle: $CIRCLE_USERNAME Job $CIRCLE_BRANCH failed' 
          webhook: $SLACK_WEBHOOK  
  build-mu-plugins:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Clone mu-plugins
          command: |
            git clone git@github.com:Automattic/vip-go-mu-plugins.git mu-plugins && cd mu-plugins && git submodule update --init --recursive && cd .. 
      # - ORB Message 
      - orb-message
```

and use **orb-message** in other commands